# os.listdir() shows nothing while it is not so

Tags: python

I am trying to sort my files for school automatically but when I try this:

```
import os, sys


path = "/Sorting for School/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

#print all dirs
for file in dirs:
   print file
```

Although there are two txt documents in dir but when I run this the output is:

```
[]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you execute an ls -l on the path? Also, that output is a bit strange, as dirs should be a list, but file shouldn't.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me as written. I agree with @spider about the output, this script would not print an empty list.

Comment: use the correct path.

Comment: if the path is *invalid*, there should be an exception raised. Also, the output wouldn't be an empty list.

Comment: Please add your filesystem layout at relevant paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine. You must be querying a wrong path.

`/dir/` means a subdirectory named `dir` in the root directory (in UNIX) or in the root directory of the current drive (in Windows).

Comment: Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. The following should work too:

```
import os

path = "/Sorting for School/"

def handle_err(err):
    print err

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path,onerror=handle_err):
    for name in files:
        print(name)
```

Comment: Now nothing prints and all the program terminates

Comment: @DavidJay       This code and your code work perfectly fine for other users and myself. Check your path.

Comment: Check your given path

Comment: I don't think this code is going to help solve the problem. os.walk is not equivalent to listdir, and also will suppress any errors listing files by default, making whatever the error is perhaps slightly more obscure.

Comment: @cms           The problem is not listdir or os.walk. Clearly the OP has issues with his path and/or Python which he cannot resolve. The answer is not right or wrong.

Comment: @hagubear I don't know that the posters problem can be deduced from the provided question. The script and output don't seem to match. os.walk will swallow errors though, unless you provide a handler.